# What is the minimum Version of the .NET Framework for an ASP.NET CORE 2.0 on Windows?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

we are currently developing an microservice application with ASP.NET CORE 2.0 and i wannt to know if this application will be running on Windows 7 or even on Windows Vista or XP.

Based on this picture :

[image]

i assumed that our ASP.NET CORE application will use the .NET Framework if running on windows.

So my question is :
How to find the minimum needed Version of the .NET Framework for an ASP.NET CORE application on Windows?
If this is a valid question to ask?

Comment: Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard. .NET Standard 2.0 requires a minimum of .NET Framework 4.6.1. So all platforms supporting it, will run on it. Keep in mind that higher/newer versions of .NET Standard may require newer versions of .NET Framework though

Comment: Please note that .NET Core 2.0 will reach End of Life on October 1, 2018.

Comment: @Mark G Thanks, will .NET Core 2.1 also run on the .NET Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to reference individual assemblies instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App meta package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4.6.1** is the minimum Version of the .NET Framework for an ASP.NET CORE 2.0 app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

- The columns represent .NET Standard versions.
- The rows represent the different .NET implementations.
- The version number in each cell indicates the minimum version of the implementation you'll need in order to target that .NET Standard version.

[image]